# IronPython 2.7.7 win32api

Tags: ironpython, revit-api, revitpythonshell

I am working in IronPython 2.7.7 and have Python 3.6 installed. I installed pywin32 in order to be able to access the win32api. I'm looking to use win32api to send keys to a dialog that pops up in Revit (not sure if this will even work)

Whenever I run python in a command window and import win32com.client or win32api, I have no problems, but whenever I tried to import those modules using IronPython, I get a "no module named win32api" error.

I'm pretty new to all of this, so I'm sure I'm missing something. Is there a way to make win32api import using IronPython? I've tried searching everywhere for an answer but haven't found anything as of yet.

Thank you!

Comment: IronPython and Python are two different distributions, you cannot use packages installed in Python from IronPython. What kind of action do you need to perform with a dialog ?

Comment: Ahh, thank you for that. Still getting to grips with it all. In particular, I'm looking to send keystrokes to a dialog that pops up from Revit. So, I was trying to use win32api to send keys to the active window. Not sure if that would work or not, but I can't get win32api to import.